# is there easy way to delete all resources in oracle cloud infrastructure compartment?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

is there an easy way to delete all resources in a compartment of the oracle cloud infrastructure tenancy?
since tracking all resources in the compartment is hard to do manually.
I know we can use [Tenancy Explorer](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/General/Concepts/compartmentexplorer.htm#:%7E:text=Resources%20Supported%20by%20the%20Tenancy%20Explorer%20%20,See%20Deployment%20Reference.%20%2031%20more%20rows%20).
But even with the **Tenancy Explorer** it is hard to do since

1. **Tenancy Explorer** does not list all resources as of now, like stream pools.
2. the process is still manual.

Answer (score 6):

You can easily do that with from shell function using oci cli as follows

```
delcmpt(){
    OCI_TENANCY_NAME=<Ur Teanncy Name>
    OCI_TENANCY_OCID=<tenancy ocid>
    OCI_CMPT_ID=$1 #OCID for cmpt to be deleted, passed as argument

    OCI_CMPT_NAME=$(oci iam compartment get -c ${OCI_CMPT_ID} | jq  '.data.name')

    echo Compartment being deleted is ${OCI_CMPT_NAME} for 4 regions SJC, PHX, IAD and BOM.

    declare -a region_codes=("SJC" 
                "PHX" "IAD"
                "BOM"
                ) # list of region codes where cmpt resources exists

    for OCI_REGION_CODE in "${region_codes[@]}"
    do
        UNIQUE_STACK_ID=$(date "+DATE_%Y_%m_%d_TIME_%H_%M") 

        OCID_CMPT_STACK=$(oci resource-manager stack create-from-compartment --compartment-id ${OCI_TENANCY_OCID} \
        --config-source-compartment-id ${OCI_CMPT_ID} \
        --config-source-region ${OCI_REGION_CODE} --terraform-version "1.0.x"\
        --display-name "Stack_${UNIQUE_STACK_ID}_${OCI_REGION_CODE}" --description "Stack From Compartment ${OCI_CMPT_NAME} for region ${OCI_REGION_CODE}" --wait-for-state SUCCEEDED --query "data.resources[0].identifier" --raw-output)
        
        echo $OCID_CMPT_STACK

        oci resource-manager job create-destroy-job  --execution-plan-strategy 'AUTO_APPROVED'  --stack-id ${OCID_CMPT_STACK} --wait-for-state SUCCEEDED --max-wait-seconds 300
        # twice since it fails sometimes and running it twice and is idempotent
        oci resource-manager job create-destroy-job  --execution-plan-strategy 'AUTO_APPROVED'  --stack-id ${OCID_CMPT_STACK} --wait-for-state SUCCEEDED --max-wait-seconds 540
        
        oci resource-manager stack delete --stack-id ${OCID_CMPT_STACK} --force --wait-for-state DELETED

    done            
 
    oci iam compartment delete -c ${OCI_CMPT_ID} --force --wait-for-state SUCCEEDED

}
```

OCI_CMPT_ID is OCID for the compartment to be deleted.
OCI_TENANCY_OCID is your tenancy OCID

usage:
shell $: delcmpt OCID_for_the_Compartment_to_be_deleted